# Get a wingpanel on ubuntu MATE 14.10

Tags: mate, wingpanel

I've been trying out various Ubuntu flavors, having decided that Xubuntu just can't handle touch very well. MATE 14.10 looks like the closest thing to Xubuntu, while being more robust and able to handle touch better.

The only thing is, I've relied on [a hack for Xubuntu that allows it to have a wingpanel](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/get-minimalistic-wingpanel-like-xfce4.html). I'd really like to have a similar setup with MATE, but I haven't been able to find a way to get it to work.

So, I'd like to know if either of these two options are viable:

1. Turning the standard MATE panel into a wingpanel, essentially permanently floating over the window-header. Honestly, this is probably what I'd prefer to do.
2. Get some kind of ppa for wingpanel that actually WORKS.

   I've tried the PPAs for super wingpanel, slim wingpanel, and neither works very well at all

Comment: In the website you mention you can see a link for instructions to do almost the same for gnome panel (back to 2010) so if you could translate the old instrucions for mate(which is a fork of gnome 2) you should be done.

Comment: Great spot! Basically, you turn on the "autohide" feature of the panel, and then delay the autohide to essentially eternity - that way, it stays up all the time, but the desktop floats underneath it. And voila! A wingpanel!

To do that back in the days of that link, you used gconf. However, now we use dconf. But in fact, I've found there's an even quicker way, just using the terminal:

dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/top/hide-delay 2147483647

That number represents the maximum time allowed for a delay... and it's ages, so works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you turn on the "autohide" feature of the panel, and then delay the autohide to essentially eternity - that way, it stays up all the time, but the desktop floats underneath it. And voila! A wingpanel!

To do that back in the days of that link, you used gconf. However, now we use dconf. But in fact, I've found there's an even quicker way, just using the terminal:

```
dconf write /org/mate/panel/toplevels/top/hide-delay 2147483647
```

That number represents the maximum time allowed for a delay... and it's ages, so works fine